# Why is oom-killer truncating the name of a presumed offending file?

Tags: linux, memory, linux-kernel

Here's an example log

```
Jan 31 11:46:15 [kernel] [753684.206218] /usr/local/Calc cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
Jan 31 11:46:15 [kernel] [753684.206244] CPU: 0 PID: 7577 Comm: /usr/local/Calc Tainted: P
```

Now here's the thing, /usr/local/Calc is not a thing on my system. There is a folder /usr/local/Calcium, and there is a perl script at /usr/local/Calcium/bin/calcium that is executed via mod_perl.

oom-killer always kills an apache process, so it would imply that the somehow this perl script is eating up the memory, but why is oom-killer truncating the name?

Answer (score 0):

What OS you use? Because according [source code](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/mm/oom_kill.c) this output should be another:

```
pr_err("%s: Killed process %d (%s) total-vm:%lukB, anon-rss:%lukB, file-rss:%lukB, shmem-rss:%lukB, UID:%u pgtables:%lukB oom_score_adj:%hd\n",
        message, task_pid_nr(victim), victim->comm, K(mm->total_vm),
        K(get_mm_counter(mm, MM_ANONPAGES)),
        K(get_mm_counter(mm, MM_FILEPAGES)),
        K(get_mm_counter(mm, MM_SHMEMPAGES)),
        from_kuid(&init_user_ns, task_uid(victim)),
        mm_pgtables_bytes(mm) >> 10, victim->signal->oom_score_adj);
```

Comment: I already mentioned this output is that it killed an apache process. That doesn't answer why it's coming up with a truncated name at the beginning of the log.

Comment: Actually, I just noticed this it says Out of memory: Kill process 1238 (/usr/sbin/apach), so even here it truncates the name of apache.